# Java string splitting with '?' character using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the following string:

`"select ?1 from students in ?2"`

I want to split it so that it becomes an array `["select", "from students in"]`, how do I achieve this? I've tried `str.split("[?\\\d]")`, but this splits the string whenever it encounters '?' or a digit, but I wanted '?' and the digit to be treated as a single string

Comment: Then why do you enclose them in a character class?

Comment: And once you get them out of the character class remember to escape the `?` as well.

Comment: `split("[?]\\d+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't surround it in `[]`:

```java
str.split("\\?\\d")
```

If you need to experiment, there are all sorts of online sites to test your regex. The first one that showed up in a search for me today is https://regex101.com/

Comment: Emphasizing the important bit: `?` is a control character for regex, and thus escaping it (`\\?`) allows you to search for a _literal_ `?` in the text. This is needed since `String#split` takes a regex pattern (as OP has noticed).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[?\\d]` which matches either a backslash or a question mark.

If you don't want the spaces in the output, you can match optional leading and trailing horizontal whitespace characters, and match a question mark followed by 1 or more digits.

```
\h*\?\d+\h*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pMoqXn/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/HY7SFg)

```
String regex = "\\h*\\?\\d+\\h*";
String string = "select ?1 from students in ?2";
System.out.println((Arrays.toString(string.split(regex))));
```

Output

```
[select, from students in]
```